# CLLocation `distanceFromLocation:` takes into account ellipsoid shape of the Earth

Tags: cllocation, cllocationdistance

I can't seem to see it in the Docs description, but does anyone know if the above method takes into account the ellipsoid shape of Earth or is it based on a spherical shape?

I assume it does, I just need to know for sure!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Proabably a spherical modell. Th ellispoidal model in vicenties formual needs much more calculation power.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it seems like `CLLocation.distance(from:)` does use *some kind* of ellipsoid earth model.

Using this Swift code

```
func testRadius(lat1: CLLocationDegrees, lon1: CLLocationDegrees, lat2: CLLocationDegrees, lon2: CLLocationDegrees, angularDistance: CLLocationDegrees) {
    let loc1 = CLLocation(latitude: lat1, longitude: lon1)
    let loc2 = CLLocation(latitude: lat2, longitude: lon2)
    
    let angularDistanceRadians = angularDistance * .pi / 180
    let meterDistance = loc2.distance(from: loc1)
    let earthRadius = meterDistance / angularDistanceRadians  // assumes circle!
    
    func coordAsString(_ loc: CLLocation) -> String {
        "(\(loc.coordinate.latitude), \(loc.coordinate.longitude))"
    }
    
    print(earthRadius, coordAsString(loc1), coordAsString(loc2))
}


// Meridians at longitudes 0°, 90°, 180° and -90°. Poles aren't well-behaved, thus ±89° instead of ±90°
testRadius(lat1: -89, lon1:   0, lat2:  89, lon2:   0, angularDistance: 178)
testRadius(lat1: -89, lon1:  90, lat2:  89, lon2:  90, angularDistance: 178)
testRadius(lat1: -89, lon1: 180, lat2:  89, lon2: 180, angularDistance: 178)
testRadius(lat1: -89, lon1: -90, lat2:  89, lon2: -90, angularDistance: 178)

// Equator from longitudes 0° to 180° and from 90° to -90°
testRadius(lat1:   0, lon1:   0, lat2:   0, lon2: 180, angularDistance: 180)
testRadius(lat1:   0, lon1:  90, lat2:   0, lon2: -90, angularDistance: 180)
```

you can test the earth's radius along some meridians and the equator. This leads:

```
6367088.045696135 (-89.0, 0.0) (89.0, 0.0)
6367088.045696135 (-89.0, 90.0) (89.0, 90.0)
6367088.045696135 (-89.0, 180.0) (89.0, 180.0)
6367088.045696135 (-89.0, -90.0) (89.0, -90.0)
6378137.000000001 (0.0, 0.0) (0.0, 180.0)
6378137.000000001 (0.0, 90.0) (0.0, -90.0)
```

so an **equatorial radius of 6,378,137 m** and — as we are using pi and radians here instead of the "circumference factor" specific to the ellipse's eccentricity (which we don't know) — a **"mean longitudinal" radius of around 6,367,088 m**.

These match the commonly used reference ellipsoid [WGS-84](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System#WGS84) also used in GPS, which makes sense as `CoreLocation` is the API for accessing the iPhone's GPS data.

Answer (score -2):

Did you read the reference?

> This method measures the distance between the two locations by tracing
>   a line between them  that follows the curvature of the Earth. The
>   resulting arc is a smooth curve and does not take into account
>   specific altitude changes between the two locations.

Comment: This does in no way answer the question of the OP. The question was whether an elipsoid or an spherical model of the earth is used. It was not questioned whether altitude changes of the geoid model are considered. Which never is the case in any formual I know.